# How to read a csv to use in pyspark MLlib?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a csv file that I'm trying to use as input of a KMeans algorithm in pyspark. I'm using the code from MLlib documentation.

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator

# Loads data.
dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("P.txt")

# Trains a k-means model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

# Make predictions
predictions = model.transform(dataset)

# Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()

silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))

# Shows the result.
centers = model.clusterCenters()
print("Cluster Centers: ")
for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-6.71,-1.14"
```

I tried to read the file as

```
dataset = spark.read.format("csv").load("P.txt")
```

But I get another error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist. Available fields: _c0, _c1
```

I'm beginner in pyspark, I tried to look for tutorials on that but I did't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. A DataFrame input of `kmeans.fit` needs to have a field "features", as the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist. Available fields: _c0, _c1` was indicating.

To do this we need a `VectorAssembler`, but before we need to convert the columns to a numeric type, otherwise we get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type string of column _c0 is not supported`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.read.csv('P.txt')
# Convert columns to float
df = df.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in df.columns))

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["_c0", "_c1"],
    outputCol="features")

df = assembler.transform(df)
df = df.drop("_c0")
df = df.drop("_c1")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This method for reading CSV files:

```
df = spark.read.options(header=True).csv('csvFile.csv')

df.show()
```

Comment: It returns the same df of `dataset = spark.read.format("csv").load("P.txt")` and I still get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist. Available fields: _c0, _c1`

Comment: Please recheck the answer. An `options` have been added. @HenriqueAndrade

Comment: I still get the same error, even when I add a header to the csv

Comment: The problem is not your data loading, you should load your data and turn your features into the features column for learning Mllib, you can see examples in below link:  https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-linear-regression-with-pyspark-and-mllib-d065c3ba246a

Answer (score -1):

`Available fields: _c0, _c1`

Check the first row of your data file. There is a high probability, that you didn't use `headers=True` parameter when saving it to hdfs while creating.

Comment: What do you mean? I used `bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal P.txt /` to save to hdfs, is there an option `headers=True` in this command?

Comment: try `head P.txt` in command line and see if your source file has any kind of header

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I tried with header and with no header

Comment: but does your source file has a header?